# Does the splitting principle define chern classes for vector bundles if they are known for line bundles?

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

Suppose we have definied chern classes $c_i$ for line bundles for all $i\geq 0$.

Let $E\to B$ be a rank $r$ vector bundle. By the splitting principle there exists a map $f:Y\to B$ such that $f^*E$ is a sum of line bundles $L_1\oplus\ldots\oplus L_r$ and $f^*:H^*(B)\to H^*(Y)$ is injective.

> Does the splitting principle define chern classes for vector bundles if they are known for line bundles?

The splitting principle says only, that **if** the chern classes are defined in two ways (natural with respect to continuous maps), one can check on line bundles if the two ways end up to be the same. I don't see how the splitting principle could be used to *define* the classes because I fear that the decomposition into line bundles (or, the space $Y$ such that $f^*E$ splits) is not unique.

Comment: You can define the "Chern classes with respect to a splitting" this way and then prove that it doesn't depend on the choice of splitting. This is the same as any mathematical situation where you define a function on a set of equivalence classes by defining it on elements and then proving that it respects the equivalence relation.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying this actually is possible but the splitting principle doesn't help and I need other arguments, right? What are those other arguments in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question in the title: yes. You are really asking if the Chern classes defined via a splitting map are independent of the choice of splitting map $f$. First note that there exists a splitting map $f$ making the cohomology $H^*(Y)$ a free module over the cohomology of the base $H^*(B)$---I believe this follows from the usual construction of a splitting map via flags of subbundles.

Given another splitting map $f': Y' \rightarrow B$, form the fiber product $Y' \times_B Y$, with the canonical map to $B$ (induced by $f'$ or $f$). The map to $B$ from this fiber product corresponds to the map $R \rightarrow S' \otimes_R S$ on cohomology, where $R=H^*(B)$, $S'=H^*(Y')$ and $S=H^*(Y)$, and is hence still injective (here we use the Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence, which actually degenerates immediately by the freeness of $H^*(Y)$ over $H^*(B)$). Inside $H^*(Y' \times_B Y)=S' \otimes_R S$ the Chern classes become equal, proving independence.